# Start fieldset class collapsible closed

Tags: jquery, html, smarty, fieldset

I have question regarding fieldset class collapsible.
How to, on page load, this field to be started in CLOSED state?

Then people will be see only `<legend>` input and when they click on it fieldset will collapse.

I need more space on web page so I need this fieldset which is collapsible CLOSED.

Thank you.

EDIT

Below is code with mentoined fieldset included:

```
    <fieldset class="collapsible">
            <legend>{lang key="field_group_title_"|cat:$group_name}</legend>
        {/if}

        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        {foreach from=$fields item=field}
            {assign var="key" value=$field.name}
            {assign var="field_name" value='field_'|cat:$field.name}
            {if $listing.$key || ($listing.$key eq '0')}
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><strong>{$lang.$field_name}:</strong></td>
                <td>
                    {if ($field.type eq 'text') || ($field.type eq 'textarea') || ($field.type eq 'number')}
                        {$listing.$key}
                    {elseif $field.type eq 'checkbox'}
                        {assign var="values" value=','|explode:$listing.$key}
                        {if $values}
                            {foreach name="checkbox_iter" from=$values item=field_val}
                                {assign var="lang_key" value="field_"|cat:$field.name|cat:"_"|cat:$field_val}
                                {$lang.$lang_key}{if !$smarty.foreach.checkbox_iter.last},&nbsp;{/if}
                            {/foreach}
                        {/if}
                    {elseif $field.type eq 'storage'}
                        <a href="{$smarty.const.ESYN_URL}uploads/{$listing.$key}">{$lang.download}</a>
                    {elseif $field.type eq 'image'}
                        {assign var="image_name" value="small_"|cat:$listing.$key}
                        {assign var="image_path" value=$smarty.const.ESYN_HOME|cat:"uploads"|cat:$smarty.const.ESYN_DS|cat:$image_name}
                        {assign var="image_title_key" value=$key|cat:"_title"}
                        {assign var="image_title" value=$listing.$image_title_key}

                        {if $image_path|file_exists}
                            <a href="{$smarty.const.ESYN_URL}uploads/{$listing.$key}" target="_blank" rel="prettyPhoto">{print_img ups=true full=true fl=$image_name alt=$image_title}</a>
                        {else}
                            <a href="{$smarty.const.ESYN_URL}uploads/{$listing.$key}" target="_blank" rel="prettyPhoto">{print_img ups=true full=true fl=$listing.$key alt=$image_title}</a>
                        {/if}
                    {elseif $field.type eq 'pictures'}
                        {assign var="images" value=","|explode:$listing.$key}
                        {assign var="image_title_key" value=$key|cat:"_titles"}
                        {assign var="image_titles" value=","|explode:$listing.$image_title_key}

                        {foreach from=$images key=indx item=image}
                            {assign var="image_name" value="small_"|cat:$image}
                            {assign var="image_path" value=$smarty.const.ESYN_HOME|cat:"uploads"|cat:$smarty.const.ESYN_DS|cat:$image_name}

                            {if isset($image_titles.$indx)}
                                {assign var="image_title" value=$image_titles.$indx}
                            {else}
                                {assign var="image_title" value=''}
                            {/if}

                            {if $image_path|file_exists}
                                <a href="{$smarty.const.ESYN_URL}uploads/{$image}" rel="prettyPhoto[gal]">{print_img ups=true full=true fl=$image_name alt=$image_title}</a>
                            {else}
                                <a href="{$smarty.const.ESYN_URL}uploads/{$image}" rel="prettyPhoto[gal]">{print_img ups=true full=true fl=$image alt=$image_title}</a>
                            {/if}
                        {/foreach}
                    {elseif $field.type eq 'combo'}
                        {assign var="field_combo" value="field_"|cat:$field.name|cat:'_'|cat:$listing.$key}
                        {$lang.$field_combo}
                    {elseif $field.type eq 'radio'}
                        {assign var="field_radio" value="field_"|cat:$field.name|cat:'_'|cat:$listing.$key}
                        {$lang.$field_radio}
                    {/if}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
        </table>

        {if $group_name neq 'non_group'}
            </fieldset>
```

Comment: Well I dont know how to ask different ;(. What to write cuz i need to know what I asked, nothing more?

Comment: There's no code in this question. You also only accept an answer for `12%` of the questions you ask. These two things combined are going to push people away from wanting to approach and answer your questions. Collapsing an item is as simple as using `display:none;` or `height:0;`. If you want another element to control the state, you'll need to use a `click function` to toggle between states.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>The legend</legend>
    <div class="frmFields hideOnLoad">
        <!-- a bunch of fields -->
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And use this jQuery when your document is loaded:

```
jQuery('fieldset').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('legend').on('click', function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().find('.frmFields.hidden').show().removeClass('hidden');
    });
    jQuery(this).find('.frmFields.hideOnLoad').hide().addClass('hidden');
});
```